# Modifying abbrvnat.bst for parens around year and no comma after author

Tags: bibtex, natbib, abbrvnat.bst

I am modifying abbrvnat.bst to (1) move year right after authors, (2) put parentheses around the year, and (3) remove the comma after the authors, and (4) have the author names listed as ,  (e.g., `Ozsu, M.T.` rather than `M. T. Ozsu`, which is how abbrvnat typesets them). I was able to do (1) by moving `format.date "year" output.check` right after authors:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  ...
```

I tried to do (2) and (3) following a number of related posts here, but I was not successful. I know that for (2) I need to modify the following definition, but I could not figure out how:

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$
       pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
  month empty$
    'skip$
    { month
      " " * swap$ *
    }
  if$
  extra.label *
}
```

I think for (3) I need to modify the following, but, again, I can't figure out how:

```
FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.names }
  if$
}
```

For (4), I have no idea really...

I would very much appreciate some hand-holding.

Comment: For (2) what result do you want when there is a month present?

Comment: I would like to ignore the month if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(3) and (4) can be solved together. In your bst file there's a line that specifies how names are formatted. It looks something like

```
{ s nameptr "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
```

and you can find it in the function `format.names` (which is around line 222 in file `abbrvnat.bst`). The symbols inside the braces represent different parts of a name and how they are formatted, e.g.

- `f.` stands for abbreviated first names (`ff` for full first names)
- `vv` stands for stuff like 'de', or 'von'
- `ll` stands for the last names
- `jj` stands for `junior` or the like
- whitespace and punctuation stand for itself

You can change this line to change the formatting of names, e.g.

```
{ s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, f.}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
```

would give you "Ozsu, M.T." instead of "M.T. Ozsu" (or "de~Ozsu, M.T., junior" instead of "M.T. de~Ozsu, junior" if you're some junior aristocrat ;-)

*Edit (Andrew Swann)* For (2) you can format the date with

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$
       pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
  "(" swap$ *
  extra.label *
   ")" * 
}
```

To get rid of the comma before the year, you can write you article definition as:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  after.sentence 'output.state :=
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  ...
```

Internally there are states `0`,...,`3` called `before.all`, `mid.sentence`, `after.sentence` and `after.block` repsectively.  `output.check` calls `output.nonnull` which in this style file only insert punctuation for states `before.all`, `mid.sentence` and `after.block`.  So for no punctuation it is enough to set the `output.state` to `after.sentence`.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll follow your guidance to get those two points done.

Comment: Your welcome.
@Andrew Swann Thanks for adding the code for (2). I somehow overlooked that.